# REST API: Cannot populate Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to pull data from an api to populate my table but nothing is being shown. How can I fix it?

**UPDATED**
When I place the GET request in either viewDidLoad() or viewDidAppear() I would receive an empty array

> result of GET is []

I have tried adding self.tableView.reload() to the viewDidLoad() but would be thrown this error

> Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'

This is my JSON response

```
[
{
"schedule_job_id": 23,
"start_date": "2016-05-01",
"end_date": "2016-05-08",
"building_id": 2,
"building_name": "Republic Plaza",
"building_block_no": "69A",
"building_street_name": "9 Raffles Place Downtown Core",
"building_postal_code": "233645",
"checklist_id": "1",
"checklist_name": "Lightning protection",
"checklist_due_date": "2016-04-12 17:00:00",
"tasks": [
  {
    "submission_id": 105,
    "task_id": "1",
    "task_name": "Inspect Carpark",
    "task_checked": true,
    "task_submitted_date": "2016-05-04 04:39:01",
    "task_comment": null,
    "task_building_level": "1",
    "task_description": "",
    "task_status": "OK",
    "total_rating": null,
    "safety_ratings": [
      {
        "submission_id": 105,
        "safety_rating_id": 79,
        "task_id": "1",
        "name": "Equipment",
        "points": "10",
        "score": "0"
      }
    ],
    "photos": []
  }
]
```

This is my GET request

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    usernameLabel.text = Data.sharedInstance.userName
    let url = "http://anyapi.com"
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
            let json = JSON(data)
            if let data = json["task_name"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                self.datas = data
                self.displayTask.reloadData()
                print("result of GET is \(self.datas)")
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

The entire tableview code can be seen here https://codeshare.io/aKknb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like json["task_name"] is not an array and isn't at first level, instead is a property of the objects in the tasks array, thats why you are getting an empty array.

You should do something like this if you intent to show the taks in your tableview

```
if let data = json["tasks"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the code which makes your HTTP request is in the wrong method. You intended it to be in viewDidLoad(), but you actually put it in didReceiveMemoryWarning()

Comment: Hi @Brett I've moved my code to viewDidLoad() but it is still not populating

Comment: What gets printed to your log by your print statements?

Comment: Remember that in viewDidLoad, the views aren't yet visible. Of course, they *may* exist by the time your asynchronous server request returns, but they may not. So it could be a timing issue. You could move the code to viewDidAppear to check.

Comment: I've tried placing it in viewDidAppear() but my console output is still "result of GET is [ ]"

Comment: Probably the structure of your JSON is the issue then. Try printing the json variable to the console. Your top-level structure is that you have an array containing one object, that object has a tasks array property which also has one object, and that object has a "task_name" property. I don't know what json["task_name"].arrayValue is meant to do, but my guess is that's where you're falling down. Might be an idea to start with a simpler JSON string and work up from there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the population in viewDidLoad try it in viewDidAppear... that way the tableview is all setup and able to correctly populate.

Answer (score 0):

you can start HTTP request in ViewWillAppear and reload the tableview.That way tableview gets properly loaded.